# NoClassDefFoundError: Changes in project import from sdk rev 17 to sdk rev 20?

Tags: android, sdk, import

I raised the same problem some time ago when moving from SDK rev 15 to SDK rev 17:

I wanted to move my projects in eclipse NOW from SDK rev 17 to rev 20 but now I cannot run simple project import examples anymore which have no problem under rev 17. Under rev 17 I just imported the project using the build path and I marked the imported project in the ORDER and EXPORT tab as to be exported and this worked fine in rev 17.

With rev 20 I get (again) the following error:

08-21 14:53:11.786: E/AndroidRuntime(558): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: simple.example.SimpleClass

The missing class is a class from the project I try to import.

Any help is again very welcome.

regards, wnck

P.S.: Why do they have to change these mechanisms again?!?

Comment: Have you tried to relaunch Eclipse ? Sometimes he's mad with this kind of stuff.

Comment: Yes, but there was no change ..

Answer (score 0):

OK, never change too many things at the same time. New eclipse, new ADT, new SDK, new JDK, nothing works anymore.

I went back to Java 6 and got this hint through a console message like

[2012-08-27 16:39:18 - SimpleAndroidProject] Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
...while parsing simple/example/SimpleClass.class
...while processing simple/example/SimpleClass.class

Then the problem got fixed after I changed the compiler compliance of the imported project to 1.6.

And my apologies to the development team! You did not change the mechanism. Sorry!

Regards, wnck